# Styling HTML page using SASS and COMPASS

Tags: html, sass, compass-sass

I have installed `SASS` and `COMPASS` using this [blog](http://iroylabs.blogspot.in/2011/05/install-compass-and-sass-in-ubuntu-1104.html).when I am using `compass create my_test_project`, it is making a new folder with name `my_test_project`.When I am going to access the folder using browser it is showing the `css files`.No `HTML` file can be seen there.So can some one tell me how to use `HTML` page there where I can use `SASS` to style them.I am just a newbie to the `SASS` so any help and suggestions will be highly apprecable.

Answer (score 1):

Sass/Compass is a tool to make the creation of CSS easier not to create HTML. You can create a HTML file inside your `my_test_project` folder and add a reference to css files which were created by sass/compass.

e.g.

```
<head>
  <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE]>
      <link href="/stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

[Compass help](http://compass-style.org/help/)

[Compass tutorials](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/)

[Sass Reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)